# Warning: require(./wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ......?

Tags: php, wordpress

I moved wordpress from one server to other...home page is running fine but when I click to category pages/links it shows these errors

```
Warning: require(./wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/server/public_html/index.php on line 17

Warning: require(./wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/server/public_html/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required './wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/server/public_html/index.php on line 17
```

I searched on google and tried accordingly but not solved.  I tried wp-codex tech like http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL but also failed. I have the wp-blog-header file in my directory but still not working....any help ...thanx in advance

Comment: edit index.php and replace line 17 with `require(wp-blog-header.php)`

Comment: Thanx for replying but Not solved  @scraaappy

Comment: you can try  that : `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`  it depends on how you move the site

Answer (score 1):

Change php version for 7. My tech.support make this and problem was done

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the problem was with the PHP version used which in my case by default was PHP 5.2 and it was throwing the 500 status code error.

When upgrading the PHP version to 5.3 the 500 status code was gone but Wordpress returned this error:

> Your server is running PHP version 5.3.29 but WordPress 5.4.2 requires at least 5.6.20.

Note to myself (and everyone else with this error): When moving Wordpress websites between different servers make sure you are running the minimum required PHP version.

Also remember:

> Note: If you are in a legacy environment where you only have older PHP or MySQL versions, WordPress also works with PHP 5.6.20+ and MySQL 5.0+, but these versions have reached official End Of Life and as such may expose your site to security vulnerabilities.

According to [WP docs](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) the recommended PHP is version 7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try the default theme and see if you still have the error.  If so the theme you are using is causing the error - as in my case.  The page that had an error was calling a file in "pages" that was not there. When I changed what is to show on that page to something current - the error went